# What is "context click" in Android SDK 23

Tags: android

There are [some new APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isContextClickable%28%29) about "context click" in android SDK 23. And I failed to find a full explanation for them.

Some search results (like [this](http://forums.sketchup.com/t/what-does-context-click-mean/13196) for SketchUp) make me think the term "context click" is similar to right-click of mouse. If this is the case here, can "context click" be triggered with touch screen as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the [code changes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/015020e%5E!/), a context-click can be implemented with either a stylus or a mouse.

Developer comment

> Based on API review feedback we should use onContextClick instead of
>   onStylusButtonPress.

Method description

> Additionally listens for mouse right clicks and calls the
>   onContextClick method for these as well.